# Eclipse configuration for running application

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I have a Java application and running good when i compile it from terminal. But, when i loaded it in Eclipse it's not running as expected.

This is how its running from Terminal

```
 java -cp:jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar:sample.jar GraphEval adjlist
```

Here GraphEval is my Main class and adjlist is my other class.

i want to load it from eclipse so i can test it and debug it.

Any idea on how to run the file from eclipse in the above format. Jar file is already loaded with no error in eclipse.

Comment: ADd the jopt jar to the build path.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Its already added.

Comment: can you elaborate on "not running as expected"?

Comment: Could you please show your project setup? I would expect a Java project with a source folder containing your classes and `jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar` on the _Java Build Path_ (shown under _Referenced Libraries_). The `sample.jar` contains your classes, right? On the command line `adjlist` is an argument and probably not used.

Comment: Why not using a Run configuration of type `Java application`? Menu Run -> Run configurations...

Comment: Silly Me!! i wasn't setting the parameter in argument in run configuration. Now its working. Thanks @LuisMuñoz